# Spring Boot - Show H2 Database Content

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I have a Spring Boot Application with a H2 database. I can add entries and I can see this entries on the swagger-ui website.

[image]

But when I open the H2 console, I can not see the tables or the columns.

[image]

Is there a way to show me the content of the database? In a readable format?

My application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mooddb;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=a
spring.datasource.password=a
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:data-h2.sql

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
```

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The h2 console can be used to execute SQL queries so that you can view the content of the database.

You can execute for example `SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE;` and you will see the result of the query in the console.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but hopefully this helps noobs.

Looks like you are:

1. Viewing an endpoint response data in Swagger - so not your H2 database nor it's data
2. That data is temporary standard (Swagger's) data and one that lives in Swagger only
3. You have the H2 database but don't have a database **table** yet

To fix you can it in the following ways:

1. Create a schema and a table model
2. Just create a table model and Hibernate will automatically create the in-memory table for you each time the application is ran

We will focus on number 2 for sake of simplicity (in more real world scenerios you need the schema's first):

1. Create a model under model package - for instance to create a user table called **Users A** do this:

   import jakarta.persistence.*;
   import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
   import lombok.Getter;
   import lombok.Setter;

   import java.io.Serializable;

   /**
   *

   - @author Admin
     */
     @Getter
     @Setter
     @Entity
     @Table(name = "usersa")
     public class UsersA  implements Serializable {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;

     @NotBlank(message = "Username is required")
     private String username;

     private Integer password;

     @Override
     public String toString() {
     return String.format("UsersA{id=%d, username='%s', password='%s'}",
     id, username, password);
     }
     }
2. That's it and each time you build and run the app hibernate will pick this up and create it for you and then it will be visible in your browser H2 Console

This obviously depends on your project having the correct dependencies like jarkata, hibernate, h2 and configured correctly in the pom.